# How to obtain states of form and Input fields in angularjs script without passing them from html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have written following code for performing validation of input fields. Here I pass the input field's states from HTML to script through a function. But I need to just call the function without passing any parameters, and the values should be directly obtained in the script without being passed from the HTML.

HTML Part:

```
<form ng-submit="LoginButton(LoginForm.$valid)" novalidate="novalidate" name="LoginForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 center-align">
      <input id="username" type="text" ng-model="username" name="username" required>
      <label for="username">User Name</label>
      <span style="color:red;font-size:small" class="help-block" ng-show="FieldRequiredFunc(LoginForm.username.$error.required,LoginForm.username.$pristine,submitted)"
        ng-bind="FieldRequired"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 center-align">
      <input id="password" type="password" ng-model="password" name="password" required>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <span style="color:red; font-size:small" class="help-block" ng-show="FieldRequiredFunc(LoginForm.password.$error.required,LoginForm.password.$pristine,submitted)"
        ng-bind="FieldRequired"></span>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 center-align">
      <button class="custom-btn" id="Submitbtn" type="submit" name="action">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Script Part:

```
 loginModule.controller("loginViewModel", function($scope) {
   $scope.submitted = false;
   $scope.FieldRequired = "This Field is Required";
   $scope.LoginButton = function(valid) {
     $scope.submitted = true;
   }
   $scope.FieldRequiredFunc = function(cond1, cond2, submitted) {
     if (cond1 && (!cond2 || submitted))
       return true;
     else
       return false;
   }
   $scope.AllFieldRequiredFunc = function(valid, submitted) {
     if (!valid && submitted)
       return true;
     else
       return false;
   }
 });
```

My question is how to obtain the `LoginForm.username.$error.required, LoginForm.username.$pristine,..` values in script from html, without passing them through the `FieldRequiredFunc()` function?

Answer (score 1):

All form is directly bound to `$scope`. so you can easily access by

`"$scope.LoginForm.username.$error.required, LoginForm.username.$pristine,..`

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.LoginButton = function() {
    console.log("is username valid" + ": " +      $scope.LoginForm.username.$valid);
  };

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Angular 1.x Application Using ng-form</title>

</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-cloak>
  <form ng-submit="LoginButton()" name="LoginForm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12 center-align">
        <input id="username" type="text" ng-model="name" name="username" required>
        <label for="username">User Name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12 center-align">
        <input id="password" type="password" ng-model="password" name="password" required>
        <label for="password">Password</label> 
      </div>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 center-align">
        <button class="custom-btn" type="submit">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <!--scripts-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Bay91ZFXNRmLikWl7Sqm?p=preview) for the same